# qmake on OS X: disable x86/i386 arch (build only x86_64)

Tags: macos, qt, makefile, qmake

I'm trying to get qmake to produce a makefile which *does not* include `-arch i386` in CFLAGS/LFLAGS and so far I'm not succeeding. I tried the following:

- `CONFIG-=x86`
- `QMAKE_CFLAGS-="-arch i386"`

and a couple of other variations. The only one that *does* work is removing `x86.prf` from `mkspecs/features/mac` but I don't think it's a proper solution.

The current commandline looks approximately like this:

```
qmake -makefile -nocache CONFIG-=release CONFIG+=Debug CONFIG+=mac 
 CONFIG+=CMDMAKE CONFIG-=x86 CONFIG+=x64 
 QMAKE_MAKEFILE=makefile_mac_Debugx64 QMAKE_LFLAGS="<...>"
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS="<..>" QMAKE_CFLAGS="<...>" QTVER=4.8.4 project.pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentative solution (need to verify a few things to confirm it, but seems to work):

1) make a separate build of Qt for x64 only, i.e.:

```
./configure -platform macx-g++42 -arch x64 -debug-and-release <...>
```

2) use `qmake` from *that* build to generate x64 makefiles.

It apparently still needs `CONFIG-=x86` but that looks to be enough to prevent stray `-arch i386` in the generated makefiles.

Comment: Note a full Qt build is probably not necessary. `qmake` is built in the configure stage, and by copying/symlinking some files or modifying paths you can fake a second Qt install for the new qmake.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that qmake uses the compiler available in the PATH. If you want to use x86_64 compiler, alter PATH (and possibly INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH) environment variables for x86_64 compiler to be available, and then run qmake.

Comment: The compiler is the same in both cases, and it can produce both x86 and x64 binaries.